# Using regression or classification for rare events

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm willing to make a model to predict the number of occurences of rare events. 
I was wondering if classification could work better than regression for that particular case ?

The events are very rare (500 in 60000 entries) and can be either 1 or 2, all others are set to 0.

Comment: You mean group both categories of rare events into one (i.e. 1 and 2 together)?

Comment: I meant instead of trying to make a regression estimate (could be 0.80 for exemple), taking this problem as a classification problem where factors would be the number of events (since the events are a count and therefore always integers)